# Does SymmetricDS propagates updates to RedShift

Tags: database, replication, amazon-redshift, symmetricds

Hello all :) SymmetricDS' [blog](http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/syncing-data-to-redshift) talks about RedShift as target-only without going into details.

Updates can be problematic in RedShift, performance-wise.

Contexte is: A one-way replication from a MySQL instance to RedShift has already been set up and databases are in synch. Rows in MySQL then gets updated.

So, the question is:

- Will the line get updated in RedShift, with the JDBC way, with the S3-bulk-load way? Does the S3-bulk even work with updates?

Additional non necessary questions:

- Performance-wise, is JDBC still ok for 1m updates a day?
- Is Vaccuum performed by SymmetricDS? Do I need to schedule it?
- If the S3-bulk-update way exists, how does it work internally? Does it loads as a sort of log table that is then propagated to the RedShift target table?

EDIT: I'd love to go parse the source code, but the feature is not yet available (last update of [publicly open source files](http://code.openhub.net/project?pid=&ipid=1960&fp=1960&mp&projSelected=true&filterChecked) date before the feature)